# Why Makefile ignore rules when is executed by XCode

Tags: xcode, makefile

My Makefile translate Java files to ObjC first and then compile them to make static library.

Everything is work right until i am trying to invoke from XCode. Make file just ignore translate rules.

Interesting part is that if i call make and generate all sources everything goes right. Updated sources are translated.

Here is my Makefile: https://github.com/actorapp/actor-platform/blob/master/actor-apps/app-ios/ActorCore/Makefile